# Existe função strpos() do php equivalente em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Gostaria de saber se existe função equilavante a strpos() do php em javascript na principalmente para o ambiente Node.js e gostaria de saber como usa-la.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trelhac, a função mais próxima da strpos do PHP no javascript é a **indexOf**, sendo que ela retorna um inteiro em relação a posição da string pesquisada:

```js
let valor = "Teste";

//Vai encontrar o valor
console.log(valor.indexOf("Tes"));

//Não vai encontrar o valor
console.log(valor.indexOf("tes"));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

---

Caso você queira verificar apenas o contido, vale a pena dar uma lida também sobre a **includes**:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: tem como eu usar isso no if?

Comment: Aqui um exemplo: https://repl.it/repls/ProudDescriptiveDiscussions